# How can I migrate mail from H-Sphere to cPanel?

Tags: email, webserver, migration, cpanel

I am moving my server from H-Sphere to cPanel and I have everything done except for the mail.

What is the easiest way to get all my mail from my old H-Sphere server and put it in my new cPanel?

Comment: Thanks for all the answers - WOW I don't think I have enough time to read them all! ;)

Answer (score 0):

cPanel doesn't provide any official tool to transfer the email from H-Sphere, possibly you can refer this from the below URL to get some more clarity on this.

http://forums.cpanel.net/f43/client-looking-migrate-h-sphere-cpanel-any-way-xfer-mail-163409.html